# CSS placeholder attribute: How to set it's width in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, placeholder

https://codepen.io/stoplion/pen/bWoPLP

I've tried a number of ways to get this placeholder's background to not look like a display block (setting it's position to absolute, setting it's width) but nothing seems to work.

Any idea how to make the background 'hug' the text as it would in an inline element?

```
@mixin optional-at-root($sel) {
  @at-root #{if(not &, $sel, selector-append(&, $sel))} {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin placeholder {
  @include optional-at-root('::-webkit-input-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }

  @include optional-at-root(':-moz-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }

  @include optional-at-root('::-moz-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }

  @include optional-at-root(':-ms-input-placeholder') {
    @content;
  }
}


input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}

input {
  @include placeholder {
    transform: translateX(-9px);
    background-color: rgba(29, 146, 237, 0.15);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: #333;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
  }
}
```

*Edit*
Inspecting the shadow dom element.. the `input::-webkit-input-placeholder` appears to get a `display: block !important;`

Better question is..
How to change the `-webkit-input-placeholder` to an inline element?

Comment: Is this what you want: provide background color only to the placeholder texts, not the whole input? Is it an X-Y problem (http://xyproblem.info/)? Because the UX it brings does not seem right to me. If this is really what you want, is JavaScript solution acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `transform:  translateX(-9px);` line makes the input text and background line up flush with the cursor.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWGrad

Removing the padding could take out the whitespace as needed too.

Comment: No, I mean the background. The background is acting like a display block element, I'd like it to work like a display inline. The pseudo element is getting a `display: block` added to it.. you can see that if you look at the shadow dom in dev tools..

Answer (score 1):

Increase your specificity. try `label + input {`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNrgjZ

Comment: Strangely, this only worked in codepen if I first changed it to `label > input {` and then `label + input {` .

Comment: I've noticed that too. Doesn't seem to work on first load.